# How to implement epub reader with Compose

Tags: kotlin, text, overflow, horizontal-pager

Is that possible to create epub Reader on Android using HorizontalPager. If not tell me how should i aproach this. I want to do it with Jetpack Compose. And how should I implement text overflow? Thanks

I tried to do it with HorizontalPager, but the problem is that i don't know how to detect overflow and i don't know how to add remaining words to next page

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.